# Could Hyperledger composer handle more than one CA (MSP)?

Tags: hyperledger-composer

I have a fabric network with two organizations with its individual MSP hence 2 MSP. Each organization manages 1 peer, I want to create a channel and have the peer of each Org to join this channel, would composer be able to handle two MSP?  The createComposerProfile.sh is able to create multiple peers but not multiple MSP.  How do I create a composer profile to associate the different MSP for the individual peer?

Answer (score 1):

With hyperledger composer, a connection profile represents a connection from one organisation to a specific channel where a business network has been deployed. Each organisation in a multi-organisation fabric topology will have connection profiles representive of their individual MSP. An organisation may also have more than one connection profile as well, for example one to perform composer runtime installations, one to transact on a business network and even one to query a business network.
createComposerProfile.sh creates a connection profile for the developer server provided by hyperledger composer and only creates a reference to the single peer defined by that developer server.

Comment: I am still not sure what connection profile I need to provide, let 's use my simple use case, 2 Org, each has its own CA, each org has a peer.  Now I want to create a channel which would be participant by this 2 org's peers.  Question is to add a participant to each org, how many connection profile would I have and what does each connection profile json file look like?

Comment: BTW, I know the answer to my simple use case, I think would have two connection profile and run add participant for the two org.  Now let's use different use case, say orgA has 3 peers, two channels created, peer1 and peer2 join channel1 and peer 2 and peer3 join channel 2.  Question is if I want to add a participant to orgA to participant to both channels then how do I add this participant to this channel and how may profile connection do I need and what do they (connection profiles) look like?

Comment: Every organisation will need connection profiles specific to that organisation. Whenever an organisation connects to a fabric it will only connect as a representitive of that organisation. Channels are the fabric isolation, each channel will have it's own ledger (therefore channels do not share data). When you connect you will only connect to a single channel. So you need connection profiles for each channel. A channel can have different peers participating so connection profiles for 1 channel can be different to connection profiles to another channel even for same organisation

Comment: This is a old question but I need to ask, If I have 2 organizations that must share the same ledger, I will need to have 2 connection profiles(CP), one for each organization ad each CP will describe only the peers in it's part of the network. Is that correct and in that case will the ledger be shared between the organizations(via the composer REST server for example)